# Cannot mount block device /dev/loop read-only

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I've got a ubuntu 14.04x64 VM running on Virtualbox on a Windows 7 x64 host machine.

I'm trying to mount an image for forensic uses, and am trying to run this command in particular:

`mount -o ro,loop,offset=1048576 -t xfs /media/mountdevicesource/ewf1 /media/mountdest`

All documentation that I've found seems to indicate that a command like this should work, however I get an error stating:

```
Mount: cannot mount block device /dev/loop0 read-only
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong? I was getting this same error on a different VM, so I re-build Ubuntu thinking it was some type of corruption problem or something, but I'm getting the same error on the new VM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Probably, your XFS filesystem has a dirty log that needs to be replayed to give you a consistent filesystem. However, the `ro` mount option prevents that.

Try mounting adding `norecovery`, for example:

`mount -o ro,norecovery,loop,offset=1048576 -t xfs /media/mountdevicesource/ewf1 /media/mountdest`

Does it change anything?

Comment: Yep, I actually found the norecovery flag before I saw your comment...adding that fixed my issue. That one little flag...

Comment: Same thing applies to `ext3` and `ext4`, though the error message is different for those.